# Error: can't get address from Geocoder

Tags: android, geocoding

```
ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(Healthcare.this);
isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
if (isInternetPresent) {
 GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(this);
 Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(Healthcare.this, Locale.getDefault());
 if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
     try {
             latitudecur = gps.getLatitude();
             longitudecur = gps.getLongitude();
             Log.d("latlong",""+latitudecur+longitudecur);
             List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitudecur, longitudecur, 1);
                        Log.e("FInalAddress1",""+address.size());
                       ## Heading ##

                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {

                }
            }
```

I wrote above code but in Log.e("FInalAddress1",""+address.size()); address.getsize() getting 0.Nothing get from this code like locality,address,etc
what is my issue on above code?
please help
Thanks

Comment: It needs internet connection. Do you put Internet permission in manifest?

Comment: did the `latlong`  print values?

Comment: yes i put internet permission in manifest and also get latitude and longitude

Comment: and the phone is having an internet connection?

Comment: yes phone also have internet connection that's why i got latitude and longitude

Comment: GPS returns latitude and longitude even if we don't have an internet connection. you can open your web browser and load any pages to check you have an internet connection

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working you can call the API provided by google

```
JSONObject jsonObject = getJsonResponse("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + mLatitude + "," + mLogitude + "&sensor=true");
    if (jsonObject != null) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject addressResult = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String formattedAddress = addressResult.getString("formatted_address");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but i know that solution but i want to get using geocoder